# Issue in merging colums of list str and dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have below scenario where list str columns  need to be merged with the dataframe.

```
 columns = ["server", "ip"]
    dataframes = [
        df1,
        df2,
        df3,
        df4,
    ]

   df_res = pd.merge(dataframes, columns )
```

df1
name , server ,
df1,df2,df3 and df4 contains column "server" and "ip" and other columns too.

So, i want to merge all the columns with server and ip in the df_res.

But i am getting issue as below:

Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed.
Please help.

Comment: What's the expected result here?

Comment: @BigBen expected result added in the description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` instead of `merge` to stack datframes vertically.

```
df_res = pd.concat([df[columns] for df in dataframes],ignore_index = True)
```

This will create a new dataframe df_res with columns =['server', 'ip'] by stacking all rows vertically. It also replaces the original index with new index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join with set_index:

```
[df.set_index(['server', 'ip'], inplace=True) for df in dataframes]
df_res = dataframes[0].join(dataframes[1:])
```